# Thunderbird: How to reply with same E-Mail (when multiple identities)?

Tags: email, thunderbird

For years I have the following problem that I'd like to solve finally.

I have my own server with an email account, e.g. `me@work.com`. Then I have another identity (email address with another domain, but belonging to my server), let's say `me2@home.org`

The Mozilla wiki [Multiple identities per e-mail account](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Multiple_identities_per_e-mail_account) says:

> When you reply to a message, Thunderbird uses the identity that matches the address the message was originally sent to, if it can find a match in the account you are working in.

Well, when I reply to an email that was sent to `me2@home.org` Thunderbird **always** uses `me@work.com` as the sender. Always.

I tried a lot but could not find a solution until now, how frustrating!

Comment: Doesn't the [Flexible Identity](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/flexible-identity/?src=cb-dl-users) extension mentioned on the Mozilla wiki page help?

Comment: Did you setup the multiple identities under the same account or do you have multiple mail-accounts with its own identity?

Comment: That's weird. Long ago it worked here. Now i tried it and it also failed to select the correct identity. Do you use IMAP or POP. (I now use IMAP.) If i copy a couple of mails to the "Local Folders" and reply from there it **does work**.

Comment: thx 4 ur feedback. / Flexible Identity plugin says it is analysing the recipient not the receiver email. / I have one mail account with 2 identities. / I am using POP on port 995 (SSL/TLS). / I am surprised, within the Local Folder it works, problem is I don't use the Local Folder. So maybe we have a bug here?

Comment: I don't know what changed (maybe the new Thunderbird 24.0) but for me it is working again (also with my IMAP-account). When replying a mail send to our info@ address i get the correct identity in the From field.

Comment: @Rik: Thanks for the tip. I updated from v17.0.8 to latest v24.0 but the bug still exists :(

Comment: I tried another Thunderbird plugin called [Correct identity](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/correct-identity/) but it seems not to work with TB 24.

I also found out that the bug mentioned has **not** been resovled for a couple of years, see here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=327713 and here: https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/incorrect_identity_on_reply Using the dropdown on each of my replies is a huge time-waster...

Comment: @M K: I tried the flexible identity plugin now. It does not seem to work either. In Filters I specified the domain name `@home.org` and choose the identity of home.org - however, it still selects the default email sender `work.com`. Could it be that as I am running Thunderbird *portable* that the addons do not work? Or did the Mozilla guys changed some functions with TB24 so that the plugins break? Anyways, just disappointing.

Comment: Seems that the Mozilla guys have a new bug in v24.1.0 which is reported here: [Bug 933555 - "Reply-to:" broken in Thunderbird 24.1.0](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=933555) - possibly this is also breaking the plugins.

Comment: Both plugins you mention are, i think, for choosing the identity for certain addressee you are **sending** mail **to** (**not** for choosing the identity based on the **incoming** mail when replying). So if you send mail to `anybody@home.org` it would work if you have `@home.org` in the list. Not really what you're after if you need to fill the complete list with all your private-contacts. Did you already rebuild your complete account-settings in the new version? (Deleting account and identities and adding them again)

Answer (score 1):

The add-on folder-account (suggested by Matheretter) helped for me too.

Enabling and disabling this add-on I figured out that the problem of the wrong identity when replying occurs when:

- the message is an automatically forwarded (aliased) message, so that my e-mail address is not in To or CC, but in Envelope-To, for example:

  default account: `me1@test.com`
  external mail address that forwards (with Envelope-To) to `me1@test.com`: `external@mail.com`
  other account in TB (but not the default): `me2@test.com`

If a message is sent to `external@mail.com` it is forwarded to `me1@test.com` and TB by message filter puts it into an inbox-folder for me1@test.com.

Without the folder-account add-on OR with the add-on, but with "use Default" in the folder properties "from-account"-setting:

- when replying the message it uses `me2@test.com` as identity and strangely not the identity related to the default account (`me1@test.com`).

With the folder-account add-on enabled AND in the folder properties the "from-account" setting set to `me1@test.com`:

- when replying the message it does use the desired identity `me1@test.com`

Answer (score 0):

After years I finally found a solution! Here you go:

1. Install https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/folder-account/
2. Create folders for each identity
3. Create filters to move incoming emails to according folders
4. Click on properties of each folder, you will see some additional options (due to the addon installed)
5. There you specify the `From Account:` for each folder.

One longtime headache and time waster removed from my life ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility, that te @work address is used, because there is no sending account @home (but there is inbox for @home).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I created the extension
[cusedar](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/custom-sender-address-reply/) ([Homepage](https://sd2k9.github.io/cusedar/)),
which is basically a merge of
[Flexible Identity](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/flexible-identity/)
and
[Reply as Original Recipient](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/reply-as-original-recipient/)
with some new features added.

It supports the outgoing direction (select from-address based on recipient) and incoming/reply direction (reply to a received mail uses again the same from-address).

Comment: I can't seem to find the addon in Thunderbird 60.7.0 :(

Comment: I guess it's hidden from search because review by Mozilla is still outstanding. If you want to give it a try nevertheless, use the [direct link](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/custom-sender-address-reply/) or head over to the [homepage](https://sd2k9.github.io/cusedar/) instead.